# Gimp: Add border to half elliptical section

Tags: gimp, borders

I am trying to add a colored border to only the half elliptical seen in the image. Is there any way to do this? I have been trying everything possible and have looked all over online. I originally cut the image out of another image, and can now paste that half elliptical anywhere I want, and can also select it and move it around. I see the dotted lines around the shape I so badly want to put a border on, but cannot for the life of me figure out how. Please help.

[image: Half elliptical]

Comment: Do you know you still have a floating selection? Anchor it to it's own layer first, then use Edit > Stroke Selection.

Comment: +1, but for cleaner results, `Select>To path`, remove the selection and `Edit>Stroke path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a commenter has said you can go to Edit>Stroke Selection but do that on it's own layer behind what you have so you don't block part of the shape and it stays editable. Also make sure you have the shape selected not the space around it. To fix that go to Select>Invert.

You can also do Select>Grow and paint inside that selection on a layer behind your image. If you are having trouble with the bottom being bordered just delete that with a rectangle selection.